# ArcGIS Reclassify Results returns nan raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff

I reclassified a raster layer as a geotiffs using ArcGIS 10.5.  The resulting reclassified raster had two values in the ArcGIS reclassify function, NoData and 1.

When I bring the geotiff into QGIS 2.18 the raster displays black with nan values.  I have tried to reclassify the resulting geotiff using GRASS but that returned an error.  Both QGIS and GRASS freak out over nan values!

How do I get this geotiff to display the nan values as transparent and the 1 values to display a color?

Comment: try to set zero values to null in with con tool or mask it out in ArcGIS in the first place. It might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  In the Layer Properties-Styles set layer enhancement to No Enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the nodata value for the raster. Using a tool such as [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) with the option

```
-a_nodata -99999
```

or some other number that will never be used in your data, will likely help to get better results in bot ArcGIS and QGIS.

I hope this helps

Comment: This approach returned a new layer with the same problem.